# InputMask for number with thousand dot and decimal comma

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to add . My purpose is to add a mask that have thousands dot and decimal comma(e.g  1.900.235,65). The problem is that I dont know how many digits can be input. And the problem is that p-inputMask of primeNg don't allow regex control(I think). Is there any ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can create your custom directive, and use it with regular expression inside, for example this code formatting string of numbers by triads (1000000 to 1 000 000)

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appFormatprice]'
})
export class FormatpriceDirective implements OnInit {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef,  private control: NgControl) { }

    @HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
    @HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
    @HostListener('input', ['$event'])

    onKeyUp(event) {
        let val = this.formatPrice(this.control.value);
        this.control.control.setValue(val);
    }

    onPaste(event) {
        let val = this.formatPrice(this.control.value);
        this.control.control.setValue(val);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.control.value) {
            let val = this.formatPrice(this.control.value);
            this.control.control.setValue(val);
        }
    }

    formatPrice(str) { return str && str.toString().replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/\s(?=\d)/g, '').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(\.|$|\D))/g, '$1 ') || ''; }


}
```

Comment: But i want to maintain the mask structure of inputmask